# Can not BroadCastState from processElement function each time

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to use BroadCastState for the first time. I tested it with a small example following the documentation. I used KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction and update the Map state from processBroadcastElement function but when I am trying to get the state from the processElement function to collect it. some times it outputs the requirement and some times outputs nothing. what is the reason behind that?

This is the code used.

```
DataStream<Tuple4<String,String,Integer,Integer>> similarityTuples = inputStream
                .keyBy(1)
                .connect(usersBroadCasted)
                .process(new KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction<String, Tuple3<String,String,Float>, String, Tuple4<String,String,Integer,Integer>>() {

                    MapStateDescriptor<Integer, String> usersBroadcastState =
                            new MapStateDescriptor<>(
                                    //"patterns", BasicTypeInfo.VOID_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);
                                    "patterns", BasicTypeInfo.INT_TYPE_INFO, BasicTypeInfo.STRING_TYPE_INFO);

                    ListState<String> usersLikedItem;

                    @Override
                    public void processElement(Tuple3<String, String, Float> input, ReadOnlyContext readOnlyContext, Collector<Tuple4<String, String, Integer, Integer>> out) throws Exception {

                        for(String user : usersLikedItem.get()){
                          out.collect(Tuple4.of(user,input.f0,1,0));
                        }
                        usersLikedItem.add(input.f0);

                        for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : readOnlyContext.getBroadcastState(usersBroadcastState).immutableEntries()){                **out.collect(Tuple4.of(input.f0,entry.getValue(),0,10000));**
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void processBroadcastElement(String s, Context context, Collector<Tuple4<String, String, Integer, Integer>> collector) throws Exception {

                        context.getBroadcastState(usersBroadcastState).put(0,s);

                    }
```

I expect this output and it sometimes outputs the what I expected without changing anything in the code(required)

```
(10,40,0,10000)
(10,20,1,0)
(20,40,0,10000)
(10,30,1,0)
(20,30,1,0)
(30,40,0,10000)
(40,40,0,10000)
```

but it some times outputs the following

```
(10,20,1,0)
(10,30,1,0)
(20,30,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

The order in which the broadcast state elements and the normal elements arrive at the operator are not guaranteed to always happen in the same order. It depends on the upstream operators which generate the elements. That is the reason why you see sometimes the full output and sometimes only the output without the broadcast state elements (all normal elements arrive before the broadcast state elements).

If you want to guarantee that you have seen all elements up to a certain point, you would need to wait for watermarks (and also generate them) and only process the elements when you've seen the respective watermark denoting that no more elements with a timestamp lower than the watermark will arrive.